# How to print SHA512 hash in C

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha512

I have the following code to calculate the sha512 hash:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main() {
    char *password = "test";
    char hash[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    SHA512(password, strlen(password), hash);

    return 0;
}
```

How to print out the calculated hash in hex?

Thanks

Comment: By enumerating the bytes in the hash and dumping their representation as hex chars (0..9,a..f) to the console. There are *multiple* ways to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `hash` to be `unsigned char hash[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH]`. Then:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
   printf("%02x", hash[i]);
}
```

Comment: I used one of those online sha512 hash calculators and the sha512 hash in hex for "test" is ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff which is not what I see when I print it out using the code that you posted. Would you please tell me why is that?

Comment: Wait my bad, it is. It has prepended ffffff to each 4 bytes of it. Why is that?

Comment: You might see the `ffffff` prepended if you have signed chars since it will be promoted to `int` and you'll get sign extension for negative values.  To fix it, cast first, like `(unsigned char)hash[i]`.

Comment: Or better still, use an `unsigned char` buffer in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!